# SQL in Hive SemanticException [Error 10004]: Line 3:5 Invalid table alias or column reference

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

trying o figure out hive sql, not having much luck with what appears to be basics, but I'm just not getting!!

I have a query;

```
select
from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(unixTimeStampField)+43200) as MyLocalTime,
cast(MyLocalTime as timestamp) as EventTime,
*
from mart.table
where names in ('abc','xyz')
```

What I am trying to do is, first convert the unixtime to my local time using **from_unixtime** then from this convert, using **cast** the column into a date/time field so my graphs can read it as a date/time vs a string value.

Am getting this error;

Error

> Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10004]: Line 3:5 Invalid table alias or column reference

Tried some suggested fixes in the chats, but none I seem to get a result with.  Thanks in advance

Comment: You can't use a column alias as a source column later in the query.  If you really need both columns, you'll have to repeat the whole expression instead of referring to `MyLocalTime`.  Either that, or use a nested query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for that, I did try and no luck unfortunately. I did though modify the unix conversion to then cast it as a timestamp, that seemed to work instead.

`cast(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(tfield)+43200)as TIMESTAMP)`

so it looks like this

```
`select 
    cast(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(tfield)+43200)as TIMESTAMP) as MyLocalTime, 
    * 
from 
    mart.table 
where 
    names in ('abc','xyz')`
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you please try this ?

If you select all columns along with something else, you need to alias the table and use it to fetch all columns.

```
select
from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(unixTimeStampField)+43200) as MyLocalTime,
cast(MyLocalTime as timestamp) as EventTime,
t.*  -- You need to call the table by alias.
from mart.table t -- alias the table.
where names in ('abc','xyz')
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I did try and no luck unfortunately. I did though modify the unix conversion to then cast it as a timestamp, that seemed to work instead.  Still trying to work my way around it, but your guys help is very much appreciated.
````
`cast(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(tfield)+43200)as TIMESTAMP)`  
````